# How to hide the partition child tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, pgadmin-4, dbvisualizer

I am creating partition tables in postgreSQL. And the partition is on date column so its nearly high in number to show in schema. I want to show only my parent table for other users.
I tried many searches but this kind of concept is not explained anywhere.
This is my hierarchy,

```
Master_table
  child_01_2013
  child_02_2013
  ....
  child_07_2019
```

so child table is in Monthly partition. I dont want to show all child table in my database. I am using Pg-admin 4 and DB visualizer(Free) tool for my works. 
Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: What is the problem if users see the partitions? You could put them in a different schema to unclutter the display.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE <partition_name> SET SCHEMA <new_schema>;`

Comment: No, this won't affect anything, except direct access to partitions. Internally, tables are not referenced by name, but by object ID, and that does not change if you move the table to a different schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to remove the partitions from the schema view, you could simply move the partitions to another schema:

```
ALTER TABLE child_01_2013 SET SCHEMA otherschema;
```

Everything will continue to work as before, but the visual clutter will be gone.

Comment: This works fine but I am trying to insert these child tables from different schema i.e parent table and trigger function were in schema 1 and child tables were in schema 2. It throws me an error while I am doing this. Child is not referenced to parent table from schema2.

Comment: Can you ask a new question for this? Please show the SQL statement and the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for dbvisualizer. For pgAdmin4 (tested on version 4.11) the partitions already show up in a folder under the main table in the object tree.  Unless you open the folder, you aren't going to see them.  You can even hide that folder altogether from the pgAdmin4 preferences setting, if you want.